# await vs while !fut.isCompleted

Tags: scala

I have the next code:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {

  println("Hello, World!")

  val fut = Future { Thread.sleep(10000); 21 + 21 }

  while (!fut.isCompleted)
    {}

  println(fut.value)

}
```

What is the advantage of using Await instead of the while loop? Is it better to use the while loop? why?

I am trying to understand Scala Futures

Thanks

Comment: Neither, but if you really need to await for a `Future` _(which should only happen in the end of the world)_ then use `Await`

Comment: But Await needs to specify some time interval (which might not be enough). However, the while loop (while blocking) will force to wait for the future to complete. Is this right?

Comment: You have `Duration.Inf` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Await` should be less CPU-intensive than a `while` loop.

The implementation you'll get with most Futures is going to eventually be using [`def tryAwait` from `Promise`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L229), which you can see is using `CompletionLatch`, which under the hood is using some low-level thread synchronization functionality so that it can actually just stall the calling thread until the latch is released. Meanwhile your CPU can go do other things and "ignore" that thread.

As opposed to `while (!fut.isCompleted)` which is just going to spend every possible CPU cycle running that check.

However, as @gatear already mentioned, you typically won't ever call `Await.ready(...)`. Typically you will attach some behavior to the future so that it will run when the result becomes available (i.e. let the Future tell things are ready, rather than being like a child in the back seat of a car, constantly asking "are we there yet?"). For example:

```scala
val loadGoogleHtml: Future[String] = /* ... */

loadGoogleHtml.onComplete {
  case Success(html) => println(s"loaded google.com --\n$html")
  case Failure(err) => err.printStackTrace()
}
```

Or you could create a new Future that applies some post-processing to the first future, e.g.

```scala
val loadGoogleHtmlAsXml: Future[XML] = {
  loadGoogleHtml.map { rawHtml => parseRawXml(rawHtml) }
}
```

The *point* of using Future is to help you out when you have some value that will *eventually* be available (e.g. some IO operation like communicating with a remote server, or a long computation that's being run on a separate thread or thread-pool), where that result is communicated via a callback function; Future is effectively a nicer way to interact with that callback-based design.

Answer (score 1):

Working with async code in Scala you'll probably interact with a framework that will either take or give you a `Future[T]`.

In a prod environment don't wait in a while block for a Future.
If **you really need to do it** use `Await`:

```scala
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  Await.result(fut, 1 minute) //will return the result
  Await.ready(fut, 1 minute)  //or just await for completion
```

Both block but regarding your question here is a snippet from the Scala doc:
Although this method is blocking, the internal use of [[scala.concurrent.blocking blocking]] ensures that the underlying [[ExecutionContext]] is given an opportunity to properly manage the blocking.

To understand some real life use-case here is how you define async actions in [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaAsync).